# Top Athlete from a statistical point of view

Tags: r

Let's say you are a junior track and field athlete specializing in 100m. 
I have the rankings of 400 junior players for each individual year since 2006 until 2016.(each year is a separate csv file (table))

And I have the rankings of senior players for each individual year since 2006 until 2016.(each year is a separate csv file (table))

The question I want to answer: is there a correlation between being a good junior athlete and your chances of being a world star?

So how should I approach this problem. I have some good skills in R. Just point me to the direction.

Comment: are you trying to build a regression model? Either way this question is out of SO's scope and will be closed soon. Have a look at [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: The way you described your problem you don’t have any data connecting junior and senior athletes, so I don’t see how you could build a model based on this data. Or do these athletes overlap?

Comment: That's my question, the athletes do overlap. They grow up in a couple of years and they start competing in seniors' competitions. How should I tackle this in R? I need a little help in building a model.

Comment: Konrad makes a great point. In order to look for an association between junior performance and chances of being a world star, you will need to know the chance that each junior athlete has of being a world star. If you have that data, you can correlate the two or create a linear model

Comment: Can you show us what your data looks like?

Comment: I've not collected all of the data yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> is there a correlation between being a good junior athlete and your chances of being a world star?

Is being a world star equal to appearing in the second group of csv`s?

Is being in the first group of csvs proof of being a good junior athlete?

Will you suppose that each name is unique and that names don't chance over time?

You might want to build a table similar to that in McNemar test.

```
            Name in top athlethes
                yes  |  no
              +------+-------  
  top    yes  |  150 |  250  
junior   no   |  250 |  550
```

Right now, I fail to see a reason why not to compute an Odds Ratio from that to answer your question.

All you needed to do is rbind all junior-CSV and `unique`the names, do the same with top-CSV and merge these two as an inner join to find overlapping names. Joins can be done using `merge`.

Comment: This is the perfect answer I have been looking for. Thank you!